# Fall back to another webservice if an API does not exist

Tags: asp.net-core, web-services

Currently we have a WebService that is being used in Production in an old .Net Framework. The time has come to create a new one using .Net Core 6 (or later). The idea is to have it launched in phases, so the applications using it, would be redirected to the new WebService and and calls which are not implemented, should fall back on the old one.

We did some research and found that a proxy can be created, however we preferred to do this entirely in the code of the new service. Is that possible and if yes how?

E.g.
To make it simple lets assume that the old service has the following calls:

```
user/GetUser
user/CreateUser
user/ModifyUser
user/DeleteUser
```

The new service has only the `user/GetUser`

If the new service receives a call to create the user, how will it re-route to the old Webservice if it doesn't have the call? Just a quick note, we won't be having a URL for the `user/CreateUser` to redirect, so needs to be checked at runtime, doesn't find it and re-routes.

Thanks in advance. Please let us know if the description is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this by having a proxy, which was deciding which webservice to call.